# Background size percentage appears different in Firefox and Webkit

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, gradient, background-size

I have a responsive circular div (made using % width, 0 height, % padding-bottom and 50% border radius) with a background gradient. If the background size is altered, they do not match in webkit / Firefox

with background-size 100% / auto they both match as expected:
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

but when i set background-size to other sizes they differ (auto 200% shown in images). Safari and Chrome show the image as expected, but firefox does not.
Webkit:
[image: Imgur]
Firefox:
[image: Imgur]

If I set the background-size to auto 300% it then displays correctly in Firefox but is then too big in webkit. If I use -moz-background-size to set Firefox to a different setting, newer versions just use the background-size instead. If I use -webkit-background-size to set webkit to the smaller version, they also get overwritten by the background-size property

Styl:

```
.glasses
    display none
    width 8%
    height 0
    padding-bottom 8%
    border-radius 50%
    position absolute
    top 37.6%
    z-index 3
    transform none
    background linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(234,246,254,1) 25%,rgba(10,39,58,1) 25%,rgba(10,39,58,1) 50%,rgba(10,39,58,1) 50%,rgba(234,246,254,1) 50%,rgba(234,246,254,1) 50%,rgba(234,246,254,1) 75%,rgba(10,39,58,1) 75%,rgba(10,39,58,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    background-size auto 200%
    background-position 0% 0%
    transition none
&.left
    left 40.2%
&.right
    right 40.2%
&:hover
    .glasses
        transition background-position 0.2s
        background-position 0% -200%
```

Comment: Ah, standardization across browsers. Good luck!

Comment: can we see your code ? is parent width set , cause vertical % padding uses width as reference., box-sizing inside ? etc ...

Comment: @GCyrillus have added this now, sorry. the parent width is %. Also, he size and the shape of the circular div is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Setting

```
background-size: 200% 200%
```

instead of

```
background-size: auto 200%
```

fixed the problem, and displays consistently across browsers.

Comment: Also had an issue with background-size in Firefox, but it was for using a single percent value (e.g. background-size: 200%). Using two values fixed it for me as well. For future reference, another thing to notice is that Firefox doesn't support background-position-x and background-position-y (however it works fine in Chrome and Safari), in this case use background-position with two values instead (e.g. background-position: 100% 100%).